# How to define a function inside a loop

Tags: python, function-pointers

Why is this not working ?

```
u = {}
for me in ['foo', 'bar']:
   def callback():
       return 'I am %s' % me
   u[me] = callback
```

The output I get is:

```
>>> u['foo']()
'I am bar'
```

It seems the `callback` is defined once at the latest iteration.

**EDIT**

As proposed by kawadhiya21, a class approach would work:

```
class CallbackFactory():
    def __init__(self, me):
       self.me = me

    def __call__(self):
       return 'I am %s' % self.me

u = {}
for me in ['foo', 'bar']:

   u[me] = CallbackFactory(me)
```

But it is far more complicated than the former approach.

Comment: try `u[me] = callback()`?

Comment: try define CallBack outside the forloop and call the function from inside the for loop

Comment: do you think types.FunctionType can help you?

Comment: You do *not* need to create a class. Just understand that Python closures are lexically scoped with late-binding behavior.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All your functions are referencing the same variable `me`. When you try and call the function, `me` has the value `'bar'`, because that's what it was when the loop ended.

If you want `me` to take a different value for each definition of the function, then each function needs its own copy of the variable.

```
u = {}
for me in ['foo', 'bar']:
   def callback(me_copy=me):
       return 'I am %s' % me_copy
   u[me] = callback
```

If you wanted, you could shorten that to:

```
u = {}
for me in ['foo', 'bar']:
   u[me] = lambda me_copy=me: 'I am %s'%me_copy
```

or even

```
u = { me: (lambda me_copy=me: 'I am %s'%me_copy) for me in ('foo', 'bar') }
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, in your example, `u['foo']` should not return a string at all, but a function handle. :) EDIT: this sentence is no longer relevant.

Second, your function `callback` uses `me`, from the outer scope. If you change this value (in your case by your loop) in the outer scope, then the function's output also changes.

To fix this, you need to make `me` part of the function's own scope, e.g. by doing:

```
def callback(int_me=me):
    return 'I am %s' % int_me
```

Comment: My mistake, I forgot `()` in the example

Answer (score 1):

You want to define a family of callbacks, not simply save a bunch of outputs, right? Define a function that binds the parameter you want, like this:

```
def make_callback(param):
    def callback():
       return 'I am %s' % param
    return callback

for me in ['foo', 'bar']:
    u[me] = make_callback(me)

>>> u["foo"]()
'I am foo'
```